# WPF data binding to Window DataContext object properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

**[Solved]**this is my first question asked here, so some mistakes could pass.
In my WPF app I want to bind in "two-way mode" all controls to corresponding properties in special object instance `BuildingManagementSystem`, which I'd like to set as Window DataContext.
But nothing works (data are not displayed). What is the right way to bind it?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    BuildingManagementSystem bms { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {    
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);
    }

    void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bms = new BuildingManagementSystem();
        this.DataContext = bms;         
}

public class BuildingManagementSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public readonly FireAlarmSystem FireAlarmSystem;

    public BuildingManagementSystem()
    {          
        FireAlarmSystem = new FireAlarmSystem();         
    }
}

class FireAlarmSystem
{

    private int alarmSmokeRate, currentSmokeRate;

    public  List<PowerConsumer> Devices { get; set; }

    public int CurrentSmokeRate
    {
        get { return currentSmokeRate; }
        set { SetField(ref currentSmokeRate, value, () => CurrentSmokeRate); }
    }


    public FireAlarmSystem()
    {
        Devices = new List<PowerConsumer>();

    }
}

class PowerConsumer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Power { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="FireAlarmGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,51,0,0" CanUserAddRows="True" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  FireAlarmSystem.Devices}"  >

    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

        <local:FireValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>

    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enabled" Binding="{Binding Enabled}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,ValidatesOnExceptions=True }" >

        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Power" Binding="{Binding Power}"></DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>



<TextBox Name="tbCurrentSmokeRate"   Text="{Binding Path=FireAlarmSystem.CurrentSmokeRate, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to create static instances of the viewmodel as shown here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModels:MainWindowVM x:Key="VM"></ViewModels:MainWindowVM>
```

When I do that then binding is easy because the properites page finds the properties for you in VS.

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,0"  
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}}">
```

But remember you need to add the namespace

```
 xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyWPF.ViewModels" 
 xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyWPF.Views"
```

This allow property binding like this:

```
    <Views:UcTitle x:Name="XTitle" ></Views:UcTitle>
    <Views:UcLegendTitle x:Name="XLegendTitle"/>
    <Views:UcSeriesTitle x:Name="XSeriesTitle" />
    <Views:UcSeriesTypes x:Name="XSeriesTypes"/>
```

And you don't have to type any of the names in...
In your case you are not using a ViewModel but you are setting the data-context correctly. So this can only be either no data to display or improper property bind.  Remember for this to work you need three things 1) DataContext 2) Vales and 3) Proper binding by Name... It's the third one that trips up folks a lot when just starting out with the great WPF binding system.

Answer (score 0):

To get MVVM working...

You will  need to update your View Model to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged to let wpf know your property changed

Use Observable collections instead of lists, ObservableCollections have the wiring to let Datagrid listview, listboxes know items in the collections have changed

Change the Field to a Property so WPF will see it...

```
<DataGrid Name="FireAlarmGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,51,0,0" CanUserAddRows="True" 
                          CanUserDeleteRows="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  FireAlarmSystem.Devices}"  >

        <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

            <local:FireValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>

        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enabled" Binding="{Binding Enabled,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,Mode=TwoWay }"  >

            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Power" Binding="{Binding Power,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBox Name="tbCurrentSmokeRate"   Text="{Binding Path=FireAlarmSystem.CurrentSmokeRate, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>


public class BuildingManagementSystem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }

    private FireAlarmSystem _fireAlarmSystem;
    public FireAlarmSystem FireAlarmSystem { get { return _fireAlarmSystem; } }

    public BuildingManagementSystem()
    {
        _fireAlarmSystem = new FireAlarmSystem();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    #endregion
}

public class FireAlarmSystem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int alarmSmokeRate, currentSmokeRate;

    public ObservableCollection<PowerConsumer> Devices { get; set; }


    public int CurrentSmokeRate
    {
        get { return currentSmokeRate; }
        set
        {

            //SetField(ref currentSmokeRate, value, () => CurrentSmokeRate);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentSmokeRate"));
        }
    }


    public FireAlarmSystem()
    {
        Devices = new ObservableCollection<PowerConsumer>();
        //Create some test data...
        Devices.Add(new PowerConsumer() { Name = "One", Enabled = true, Power = 100, Priority = 1 });
        Devices.Add(new PowerConsumer() { Name = "two", Enabled = false, Power = 101, Priority = 2 });
        Devices.Add(new PowerConsumer() { Name = "three", Enabled = false, Power = 103, Priority = 3 });
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    #endregion
}

public class PowerConsumer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Power { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes out here

1. Seems like BuildingManagementSystem is intended to be your data-context

In place of BuildingManagementSystem bms { get; set; } write the below code:

BuildingManagementSystem bms =new BuildingManagementSystem ();

2. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged event in your ViewModels to reflect the changes on UI
3. If you intent is to assign values to each of the underlying child view-models, make use of parameterized constructors to pass and assign values. Simply instantiating the child viewModels in parent will not serve any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I've found a mistake, it was defining `FireAlarmSystem` as `readonly`, it shold be a property.
2 Stuart Smith, you're right with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I have an abstract class-ancestor `BuildingSystem`, which implements this interface. I've forgot to post it.